# Kurento not recording video

Tags: kurento

I have an application using an older version of Kurento, KMS 5.1.0.  It's been running well for a while, but just decided to stop recording videos on the server sometime within the last couple of weeks, and I have no idea why, and not really sure how to debug it.  It still works on Chrome /w Android.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is not that it's not recording the video, but that it's getting no video at all. A lot of things have changed in the browser's implementations since v5 of Kurento, so I'm surprised that it has been working so far! The changes in the implementation of browser forces other peers to adapt to those changes, or the negotiation wouldn't be possible.

My recommendation is that you update to the latest KMS version (6.5.0 as of today), to keep up to date with current clients.

Comment: Thanks igracia.  Since I have to switch over to KMS 6, I think I will try out elasticRTC.  Can you point me to some additional documentation / sample apps beyond what is on GitHub, if you know of any?  Thanks.

Comment: @Jimmy There are several examples in Github, but they are not official. Just search for Kurento there, and you'll find many repos from other users that hold apps. You can also ask in the official mailing list, to see if there are some users that can help you.